# Unable to compile web project with sub-web-projects with MSBuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, continuous-integration, vs-web-application-project

I'm trying to compile a web project solution using MSBuild which has other web-projects as sub-folders, and can't get around the problem:

> ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

I have created a site in IIS and created virtual directories (as it suggests) for all sub-folders which are also web projects, and it now compiles in VS2010, but still get this for the root project when using MSBuild (the aspnet_compiler.exe).

Is there a way I can see how this works in VS so I can use that command-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it [seems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) you can just use VS to do the rebuild using devenv.com:

> "C:\progfiles\msvs10\common7\ide\devenv.com" "SolutionFile.sln" /Rebuild